# NSDictionary find index of value of a key

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

So I have two dictionaries that are structured as such:

```
{
 version: "1.0",
 timestamp: 1123,
 data: [
  {
   foo: "0.0026",
   bar: 548,
  },
  {
   foo: "0.0065",
   bar: 341,
  },
 ],
revision: 1234
}
```

and as such

```
{
 version: "1.0",
 timestamp: 1123,
 data: [
  {
   foo74: "0.0026",
   bar: 340,
  },
  {
   foo74: "0.0378",
   bar: 548,
  },
 ],
revision: 2345
}
```

These are loaded in asynchronously from two separate API calls and then the `UITableView` is reloaded. 
In each `UITableViewCell` I need to match up the `bar`values to display the relevant data in each cell. For example: at index 0 of the `UITableView` will contain `bar: 548` and foo: `"0.0026"` however, in that same cell I need to include the value of `foo74` which in this case is `"0.0378"`. Meaning that I have to go through the second data set and find the index at which `bar` is equal to `548`.

I am trying to figure a way to do this inside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` without having to iterate through each one of the second data entries for each one of the first (resulting in O(n^2) runtime).

I have tried `allKeysForObject` by passing the value of `548` into the second data set, and it doesn't seem to return anything.

I considered sorting them before hand, which would give me slightly better runtime.

I am really just looking for something that will avoid me having to do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [[dict2 objectForKey:@"data"] count]; i++) {
        if(dict1[@"data"][indexPath.row][@"bar"] == dict2[@"data"][i][@"bar"])
        {
            NSLog(@"found");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before your table view is reloaded, you should index the data in dict2 into a NSDictionary with the key is the value of "bar" and value is the data you want to get (in this case is value of "foo74").

Inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, call `indexDict[dict1[@"data"][indexPath.row][@"bar"]]` to find the data. If this value is nil, that means not found.

The loop for indexing takes O(n) runtime and each call to find data  takes O(1) runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There is one another option you can work upon as follows:

You need to convert dataDict2 data array to dictionary
like

```
for (int i = 0;i < [dataArray2 count]; i++) {

               [newDataDict addEntriesFromDictionary: @{[[dataArray2 objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"bar"] : [[dataArray2 objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"foo74"]}];

    }

    [newDataDict objectForKey:@"548"]; // which will be 0.0378
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all keys as `[Dic AllKeys]` and all values as `[Dic AllValues]`. Then you can foreach all keys like  `[Dic valueForkey:[[Dic AllKeys] objectAtIndex:0]]` . by that you can take first dictionary keys and join it with second dictionary.